# How does TabPilot remotely install apps without user interaction?

Tags: android

I want to build an app that would remotely install other apps on controlled tablets.

I know from the Android SDK documentation that you cannot install an APK programatically **without user interaction**, and rightfully so!

However, it looks like Tab Pilot http://www.tabpilot.com/ does this in background.

Any idea on how they do it? Apparently, the tablet needs not be rooted.

Comment: TabPilot might not be a completely native app. I think it might be a hybrid one. All the other things/app that is seen on screen will be on cloud and they would override all hardware button once their app is on foreground. When teaching session is over, close the app remotely.

Comment: @Kaustuv sorry I don't see how your answer comes anywhere close to relating to my question